# deleting a file from directory using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to delete files from a directory using check-box for selecting files and button event for deleting selected ones.

so basically I want it looks like this:

[image]

the problem, I retrieve the files via php but I put this checkbox via jquery
and I dont know how to relate these elements with each other

How can I delete these selected files?

My code is down here:

```
$dir    = 'C:\directory\of\files\here';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$cnt = count($files1);
//var_dump($cnt);
echo "<h1><u> delete files from directory </u></h1>";
echo "<div class='container'>";
for($n=0; $n< $cnt; $n++)
{
if ( ($files1[$n])!= '.'  && $files1[$n] != '..')
        {

     print_r("<input type='checkbox' />".($files1[$n])."<br/> ");       
        }
}
echo "</br>";
echo " <button>DELETE</button>";

echo "</div>";

?>


<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      </script>
</head> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete file with `unlink` function. Set name of a file as a checkbox value.

Comment: @u_mulder but as you see number of files are not static, indeed dynamic that's why I cannot set checkbox value for them... I would appreciate if you show me how to use it under this circumstance because this is where I stuck

Comment: if the nr of the files is not static you can name your checkboxes like file[] so in the POST will appear as an array

Comment: @SzántóZoltán I checked your sugesstion but I stuck on file[] can you give a solution

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a `<form>` tag, which creates a form.

Then you'll need to set a name and value to the checkboxes.

Last but not least, when the form is submitted, PHP checks if `$_POST['filenames']` is set, if yes, it loops the array and deletes all the files that are selected.

```
<?php
$dir    = 'C:\directory\of\files\here';

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  == 'POST' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['filesnames'] ) ) {
                foreach( $_POST['filesnames'] as $key => $file ) {
                        unlink( $dir . '\\' . $file );
                }
                echo 'Files deleted';
        }
        else {
                echo 'No files selected';
        }
}

$files1 = scandir($dir);
$cnt = count($files1);
//var_dump($cnt);
echo "<h1><u> delete files from directory </u></h1>";
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
for($n=0; $n< $cnt; $n++)
{
if ( ($files1[$n])!= '.'  && $files1[$n] != '..')
        {

     print_r("<input name='filesnames[]' value='".($files1[$n])."' type='checkbox' />".($files1[$n])."<br/> ");       
        }
}
echo "</br>";
echo " <submit>DELETE</submit>";
echo "</form>";

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: there is a problem related with curly braces... I couldnt solve can you recheck your suggestion?

Comment: ok I checked it still doesn't delete + when I perform the action it causes two errors

1 ) Notice: Undefined variable: POST 

2)  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 

can you help me about it?

Comment: yesterday I fixed that it still doesn't work ...where it gives the errors above that I mentioned @LinkinTED

Answer (score 0):

Here is your main file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>delete</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myform">
    <?php
    $filesss = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__), array('..', '.'));

    foreach ($filesss as $file) {
        echo "<label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$file'>";
        echo "$file </label><br>";
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myform").submit(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and your delete file

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['file'] as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Basically what you do with this code is that you collect file paths from the page and you send via ajax to delete.php what deletes the files (with unlink).

But ALWAYS use form and input validation especially when you want do delete files!

Comment: @Szanto_Zoltan
ok this looks like what I am searching for...

i made like this
`for($n=0; $n< $cnt; $n++)
{
if ( ($files1[$n])!= '.'  && $files1[$n] != '..')
  {
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$files1[$n]'>";
   
  }
}`
but it didnt show names of the files in the directory... So, I am making a mistake on somewhere ... can you show me some more clue

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
<?php
$dir = 'C:\directory\of\files\here';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  foreach($_POST['files'] as $file) {
    $file = addslashes($file);
    if(is_readable($file)) {
      unlink($file);
    }
  }
} else {
  $files = scandir($dir);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#deleteFiles').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          url: location.href,
        }).done(function() {
          alert('Done !!!');
        });
      })
    });
</head> 
<body>
<h1><u> delete files from directory </u></h1>
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" method="post" id="deleteFiles">
    <?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
      <?php if($file === '.' || $file === '..') { continue; } ?>
      <lable>
        <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="<?php echo $file; ?>">
        $<?php echo $file; ?>
      </lable>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @taras_repa it gives error  "Notice: Undefined variable:" for the line:  <?php foreach($files as $file): ?>

Comment: @gobo Sorry. Please replace next code 

$.ajax({
    url: location.href,
    data: $('#deleteFiles').serialize(),
    method: 'post'
}).done(function(data) {
    alert('Done');
});